# How should I count the number of occurrences of a character at the beginning of a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string similar to this `,,,foo,bar` and I need to count the amount of "," at the beginning  of the string in java any ideas?

Comment: Clarify your question with what you mean by "at the beginning"? Are you searching the string until you get to a non-comma character? A-Za-z0-9?

Comment: yes, in the case of the example It should return 3

Comment: I tried this: int j=0;
       for (int x = 0; i<lala.length(); x++) {
        if (lala.charAt(x)==',') {
         j++;
        }
        else {
         break;
        }
       }</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use regexp:

```
public static int countCommasAtBegin(String str) {
    Matcher commas = Pattern.compile("^,*").matcher(str);
    if (commas.find()) {
        return commas.group().length();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but for such trivial task I prefer to use simple loop.

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for :) I'll use it

Answer (score 2):

Have a `counter` variable which counts the number of occurrences. Then loop through the entire `String`, using `charAt(i)` to get the `char` at position `i`. Test to see if it's equal to `charAt(0)`. If it is, increment `counter` and if it isn't, `break` out of the loop.

Comment: +1 for giving the logic but not the code. Questions smells like homework, this is the best way to answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [String javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It contains methods you can use to get the length of the String and get characters at certain positions.

Answer (score 1):

If starting characters are known then build a regex pattern and get the first group. First group string will contain the exact match of desired sequence, length of this string is the resultant count.

Comment: Good idea! I will use this pattern: [,{2,}]

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop (while or for) containing a if with a condition of equality that increments a counter if true should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This quick-n-dirty solution worked for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = ",,,foo,bar";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != ',')
            break;
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("count " + count);
}
```

Update: just realized that you only need to count the ',' at the beginning of the string and not the middle. I've updated the code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you  don't want to use any any external jars just write a simple function:

```
public static int countAtBegin(String str, char c) {
    for (int ret = 0; ret < str.length(); ret++) {
        if (str.charAt(ret) != c)
            return ret;
    }
    return str.length();
}
```